# Execute Activity after the completion of all the activity

Tags: amazon-swf

I have an activity(say actN) that is dependent on **N** number of activities. All the **N** activities are executed in parallel. After the completion of all the activities i want to execute activity actN. I want to do this without using any @Asynchronous annotation as @Asynchronous tag is not working for me.

```
public Promise<Integer> executeLastactivity(List<Promise<Integer>> prm){

//TODO


}
```

Comment: I think the real question is, why isn't `@Asynchronous` not working? Are you sure that you are running/compiling your code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of any type that extends *Collection* should be annotated with [@Wait](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/annotations.html#annotations-waitnowait). It is necessary because the Flow framework relies on Java reflection to determine if type of the argument is [Promise](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/Promise.html). But Java doesn't expose generic types through reflection.

So your method signature should look like:

```
@Asynchronous
public Promise<Integer> executeLastactivity(@Wait List<Promise<Integer>> prm){

//TODO

}
```

Comment: Another option is to use [`Promises.listofPromisesToPromises(List<Promise<T>> promises)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/Promises.html#listOfPromisesToPromise(java.util.List)) and then you just have a single `Promise<List<Integer>>` as your input.